# Represent generic class inheritance in UML

Tags: generics, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

Is this the correct way to represent the following code in a UML Class Diagram?

**CODE:**

```
public class CustomerRepository 
    : EntityFrameworkRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository 
{ }
```

**UML:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Realised first answer wasn't correct after posting.  The [UML spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta1/PDF) says (section 7.3.4):

> A bound element has the same graphical notation as other Elements of
>   that kind. A TemplateBinding is shown as a dashed arrow with the tail
>   on the bound element and the arrowhead on the template and the keyword
>   «bind». The binding information may be displayed as a comma-separated
>   list of template parameter substitutions

I tried to create an example in MagicDraw:

[image]

For some reason it wouldn't let me enter the bind clause (contents of angle brackets on the dashed arrow): it should read `<RepositoryType -> Customer>`.  Also the `RepositoryType` parameter shouldn't be of type String (tool again).

The key point is: the parameter binding is specified on the binding relationship, not in the parameterised class.  Which means you can have multiple bindings with different types.

hth - apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The problem is when you have two classes inheriting from `EntityFrameworkRepository<T>`, say a `CustomerRepository` and an `OrderRepository`, then you need to have two separate `EntityFrameworkRepository` base classes.